# Automatic ID generation with create! block in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use the following inside my model:

```
create!(
  :title         => entry.title,
  :link          => entry.url,
  :published_date => entry.published,
  :entry_id         => entry.id,
  :category => thing,
  :author => entry.author,
  :user_id => user.id
)
```

This fails with `Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'` when adding anything past the first entry since the id column is being set as 0.  Is there a way to auto-increment the id using the above code?

Thanks

Comment: Why on earth are you setting the id column to 0? IDs should be auto-incremented columns and handled completely by your database.

Comment: @sevenseacat When I do nothing, the id is being set to 0 automatically.

Comment: and why is that? What have you done to your schema?

Comment: @sevenseacat Nothing that I am aware of. At one point I did change the ID column to a string (don't laugh), but then I changed it back to an integer.

Comment: I'm not laughing, I'm smacking my forehead. And did you reset it back to being auto-incrementing when you did that?

Comment: @sevenseacat I'm guessing that I did not...I used change_column :table, :id, :string, then reverted it later.  What would I need to do to set it back to auto-increment?

Comment: Simplest way is just to recreate the table.

Comment: @sevenseacat Yep, that fixed everything. Feel free to leave an answer with whatever and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never need to manually specify the ID when creating new instances; Rails will automatically create the auto-incrementing column to handle generating unique IDs for you.

In this case, if you have tampered with the ID column and changed its type, the easiest way to reset this is to simply recreate the table.